# Override copyWithZone: in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsobject, nscopying

Can someone tell me how can one override `-copyWithZone:`

Assuming I have one NSString object, NSInteger object as class members.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? Please provide code of what you have tried. And please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: Why do you need to override `copyWithZone:` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass the class for which you need to override `copyWithZone:`.

Your sublclass should use the method similar to below:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    YourClass *copy = [[YourClass alloc] initWith...:<value>];
    return copy;
}
```